# SQL Server Statement to DAX formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I need help converting a SQL query to DAX cause at this point my DAX code looks weird and it doesn't work.

There are data in USD and DOP currencies, so I would like to have a result like this:

[image]

T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @CURRENCY INT;

SET @CURRENCY = 1

SELECT
    A.REASON,
    --calculation for dop currency
    CASE @CURRENCY
        WHEN 1 
            THEN
                CASE A.CURRENCY
                    WHEN 1 THEN SUM(ADJUDICADO) + SUM(MONTO_COTIZADO)
                    WHEN 2 THEN (SUM(ADJUDICADO) + SUM(MONTO_COTIZADO)) / 57
                    ELSE 0
                END
        WHEN 2 
            THEN
                CASE A.CURRENCY
                    WHEN 1 THEN (SUM(ADJUDICADO) + SUM(MONTO_COTIZADO)) * 57
                    WHEN 2 THEN SUM(ADJUDICADO) + SUM(MONTO_COTIZADO)
                    ELSE 0
                END
        ELSE 0
    END AS DOP,
    --calculation for usd currency
    CASE @CURRENCY
        WHEN 1 
            THEN
                CASE A.CURRENCY
                    WHEN 1 THEN SUM(ADJUDICADO) + SUM(MONTO_COTIZADO)
                    WHEN 2 THEN (SUM(ADJUDICADO) + SUM(MONTO_COTIZADO)) / 57
                    ELSE 0
                END
        WHEN 2 
            THEN
                CASE A.CURRENCY
                    WHEN 1 THEN (SUM(ADJUDICADO) + SUM(MONTO_COTIZADO)) * 57
                    WHEN 2 THEN SUM(ADJUDICADO) + SUM(MONTO_COTIZADO)
                    ELSE 0
                END
        ELSE 0
    END AS USD
FROM 
    --TMP TABLE 
    (SELECT
         'Not Enough Founds' AS REASON,
         23423423423.321 AS ADJUDICADO,
         -34234234234.55 AS MONTO_COTIZADO,
         1 AS CURRENCY
     UNION
     SELECT
         'Fees' AS REASON,
         23423423.2 AS ADJUDICADO,
         -423423.09 AS MONTO_COTIZADO,
         2 AS CURRENCY
     UNION
     SELECT
         'Others' AS REASON,
         123123321.21 AS ADJUDICADO,
         -1231231.53 AS MONTO_COTIZADO,
         1 AS CURRENCY) A
GROUP BY
    A.REASON, A.CURRENCY
```

Basically the parameter 1 will convert the currency from USD to DOP and vice versa if we select 2, for the data in USD and DOP respectively.

At the end I don't know if it's possible to have a calculation table with those case and grouping calculations, this is the code I have right now:

```
Monto = 
    VAR CURRENCY = SELECTEDVALUE(DIM_MONEDA[key])
    VAR TOTAL = 0
    RETURN (
        IF(CURRENCY = 1, SUMX(FILTER(FACT_DEALS, FACT_DEALS[MONEDA_KEY] = 1),
            TOTAL = TOTAL + (SUM(FACT_DEALS[ADJUDICADO]) + SUM(FACT_DEALS[MONTO_COTIZADO])) / 57 ),
                IF(CURRENCY = 2, SUMX(FILTER(FACT_DEALS, FACT_DEALS[MONEDA_KEY] = 2),
                    TOTAL = TOTAL + (SUM(FACT_DEALS[ADJUDICADO]) + SUM(FACT_DEALS[MONTO_COTIZADO])),
                        IF(CURRENCY = 3, TOTAL = TOTAL + (SUM(FACT_DEALS[ADJUDICADO]) + SUM(FACT_DEALS[MONTO_COTIZADO])))
    ))))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well doing some research on [Microsoft DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax), I found the way I can translate the query,

```
Monto = 
VAR CURRENCY = SELECTEDVALUE(DIM_MONEDA[key])
RETURN (
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        CURRENCY = 1, SUMX(FILTER(FACT_DEALS, FACT_DEALS[MONEDA]="DOP"), FACT_DEALS[MONTO_COTIZADO])
            + (SUMX(FILTER(FACT_DEALS, FACT_DEALS[MONEDA]="USD"), FACT_DEALS[MONTO_COTIZADO]) * 57),
        CURRENCY = 2, SUMX(FILTER(FACT_DEALS, FACT_DEALS[MONEDA]="USD"), FACT_DEALS[MONTO_COTIZADO])
            + (SUMX(FILTER(FACT_DEALS, FACT_DEALS[MONEDA]="DOP"), FACT_DEALS[MONTO_COTIZADO]) / 57),
        CURRENCY = 3, SUM(FACT_DEALS[MONTO_COTIZADO]) + SUM(FACT_DEALS[ADJUDICADO])
    )
)
```

Basically with SWITCH and SUMX I found the way to calculate the amount...